# Exporting QML in QGIS Graphical Modeler

Tags: qgis, layers, export, qgis-modeler, qml

In QGIS graphical modeler, is it possible to set and export *.QML* extension of an output layer (adding *.qml* to the others extensions *.shp*, *.shx*, *.dbf*, ..)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I realise your question specifically notes shapefiles, but if you output to GeoPackage, you can use the [Package layers algorithm](https://docs.qgis.org/testing/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/database.html#qgispackage).

Alternatively you could create a [processing script](https://docs.qgis.org/3.28/en/docs/user_manual/processing/scripts.html) that saves the layer style to a QML on the file system:

[image]

Here is is simple script that will take an input map layer and save its current symbology as defined in the map to a .qml style with the same path/basename as the input layers data source. Note it will only work with simple file system datasets, not web layers, layers from delimited text files or layers in a database format, like GeoPackage or FileGDB.

```
from qgis.processing import alg
from qgis.core import QgsProcessingException
from pathlib import Path

@alg(name="savestyle", label=alg.tr("Save Style"), group='examplescripts', group_label='Example scripts')
@alg.input(type=alg.MAPLAYER, name="INPUT_LAYER", label="Input Layer")
@alg.output(type=alg.FILE, name='OUTPUT_STYLE', label='Output style file')
def save_style(instance, parameters, context, feedback, inputs):
    """Save style file"""

    try:
        lyr = instance.parameterAsLayer(parameters, "INPUT_LAYER", context)
        path = Path(lyr.dataProvider().dataSourceUri())
        if not path.exists():  # not a filesystem path
            raise QgsProcessingException("The layer path does not exist on the filesystem")
        path = f"{path.parent/path.stem}.qml"
        lyr.saveNamedStyle(path)
        return {'OUTPUT_STYLE': path}
    except Exception as err:
        raise QgsProcessingException(f"Unable to save style for layer {parameters['INPUT_LAYER']}:\n{err}")
```

This processing script can then be added to a model:

[image]

[image]